# How to make script support file:/// notation?

Tags: bash, scripts

When I copy any file and paste it in console or text editos it is passed as

> file:///home/user/path/file

when I pass it to script it is not found

What is the easiest way to convert that to normal linux path or somehow make script support it?

for example

> cat file:///home/user/path/file

says

> No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the `file://` prefix from the URL, you can use **sed**:

```
echo "file:///home/user/path/file" | sed "s/^file:\/\///g"
```

What the above does:

- Displays the URL to the standard output (so it can be modified with sed)
- Replaces all occurrences of `file://` in any line that begins with `file://` with nothing. This effectively removes `file://` from the URL leaving only `/home/user/path/file`

To use this from a script you can try the following:

```
cat $(echo "file:///home/user/path/file" | sed "s/^file:\/\///g")
```

Now the error message is:

```
cat: /home/user/path/file: No such file or directory
```

*(Please note that it refers to the correct filename instead of the URL.)*

It would be much cleaner to store the converted filename in a shell variable and use it afterwards.

```
MYFILE=$(echo "file:///home/user/path/file" | sed "s/^file:\/\///g")
cat $MYFILE
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of any commands that convert between file urls and file paths, but you can convert with python, or any other language with bindings to gio. E.g.:

```
$ python -c 'import gio,sys; print(gio.File(sys.argv[1]).get_path())' file:///home/user/path/file%20with%20spaces
/home/user/path/file with spaces
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Your command also works with umlauts, which is perfect for my use case.

Comment: Using this solution, rather than rolling your own, has the further advantage that support for protocols other than `file:///`, such as `sftp://`, drops out of the box for free, via gvfs.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `urlencode` (`sudo apt-get gridsite-clients`):

```
$ echo "$(urlencode -d "file:///folder/with%20spaces")"
file:///folder/with spaces
$ echo "$(urlencode -d "file:///folder/with%20spaces"|cut -c 8-)"
/folder/with spaces
```

If you don't need hexadecimal support, you can just use `cut -c 8-`. Alternatively, you could use urlencode with any other method of removing the `file://` (sed, brace expansion, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this is bash itself. Try the following

```
echo "file:///home/user/path/file" | cut -d'/' -f3-
/home/user/path/file
```

It will delimit till file:`//` and the rest will be echoed on the terminal.

Comment: Nice, +1. However, `cut` is in no way part of `bash`.

Comment: This will work incorrectly if the path doesn't start with `file://`, though.

Answer (score 0):

You  can use this, assuming `file_path` contains the path:

```
#!/bin/bash

file_path='file:///home/me/Desktop/path test'

file_path="${file_path#file://}"

echo "${file_path}"
```

which prints `/home/me/Desktop/path test`. This allows it to work with or without `file://`, using only Bash string manipulation.

---

You can add this to a function (in `.bashrc`) for ease of use:

Function:

```
norm_path() {
    echo "${@#file://}"
}
```

Usage:

```
cat "$(norm_path file:///home/user/path/file)"
```