# Dynamic template names for Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, nautilus-actions, templates, caja

I really like that I can add templates to `~/Templates` in order to create new files by a template with `Nautilus` or `Caja`.

What I like to have improved is the naming of my files.

They are named: `Unknown-[Template-Name-Here]`. I'd prefer such a format `[Template-Name-Here]-[Date]` while the date should be in the format `YYYY-mm-dd`.

Is something like this already possible?

How can I automatize the renaming of my template's file names :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case nautilus scripts are probably the best solution. They are placed in `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts` for nautilus or in `~/.config/caja/scripts` for caja and in either case need to be made executable (`chmod ug+x $path_to_script`).

This script will create a dialog box asking for your choice of template and then create a file based on that template in the current directory, with your desired format:

```
#!/bin/bash

current_nautilus_dir=$(python -c 'import gio,sys; print(gio.File(sys.argv[1]).get_path())' "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI")
# python-free:
# current_nautilus_dir=$(echo "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI" | sed -e 's/%/\\x/g' -e 's_^file://__' | xargs -0 printf "%b" )
template_dir=$(xdg-user-dir TEMPLATES)
template_name=$(find "$template_dir" ! -type d -print0 | sed 's_'$template_dir'/__g' | xargs -0 zenity --list --column=Template)
template_short_name=$(basename "$template_name")
destination_name="${current_nautilus_dir}/${template_short_name}-$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")"

if [ -f "$destination_name" ]
then
    notify-send "Destination already exists"
else
    cp "${template_dir}/${template_name}" "$destination_name"
fi
```

This converts the URI to a path, using the script from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74756/how-to-make-script-support-file-notation/76266#76266).