# How to create Template file which create a new file having file creation date and time?

Tags: 18.04, templates

In /Home/Templates directory, we can put template file. So we can create new file by right clicking. Is there any way we can create new file which have current Date and Time. Something like log file. Which have date and Time as very **first line**. Or in the **name** of file.

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776803/dynamic-template-names-for-nautilus) is slightly similar (at least the second part — having the date in the name of the file).

Comment: Creating a file having date in name is can be done by touch command. But here I want it as Template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the **solution** for which I am looking for. But certainly good one.

1. Step-I

   - Create a file and put following command

     ```
     #!/bin/bash

     touch $(date +"%Y-%b-%d_%H:%M:%S")
     ```
   - Mark file for execution

     ```
     chmod +x file
     ```

     **Or** Right click on file and select **properties**. Under Permission tab, tick **Allow executing file as program**
2. Step-II

   - Install `dconf-editor` and run it.
   - Move to `org/gnome/nautilus/preferences`.
   - Right click on `executable-text-activation`.
   - Select **launch** from drop down menu.
3. Step-III

   - Put that file in Templates folder.
4. Step-IV

   - At any location (e.g. Desktop or Documents etc.), just right click and create that file there.
   - Now double click it, it will create file with Date&Time as name.

> Bash command for creating file with Name as DateTime and also as first line

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $(date +"%Y-%b-%d_%H:%M:%S") > $(date +"%Y-%b-%d_%H:%M:%S")
```